# How can my iOS app see what contacts are in a group message?

Tags: ios, swift, contacts, imessage

I am using the latest Xcode (13.1) on the latest macOS (Monterey 12.0.1), using Swift, and I would like my iOS app to read the contacts in a specific group message in Messages. The last I looked, Apple does not allow this, and I have found not information to answer this question on Apple's developer website or on stackoverflow, but I would like to know if this has changed since the latest release of iOS.

Comment: I believe that you still cannot do it. Apple is quite strict on privacy

Comment: @Scriptable You're probably right. I wanted to gratify my wishful thinking. Sometimes I learn unexpected things when I ask a question.

Comment: What is your use-case for this?

Comment: @johnnykehr I would like my iOS app to put all those contacts in the group message into a Group, and if one of the contacts in the group message does not exist as a Contact in the Contacts app, then I would like to create a Contact out of that contact in the group message and put it in the Group I created.

Comment: Nothing has changed regarding your question.

Comment: @HangarRash I was afraid of that. Yeah. Still wishful thinking.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is no, this cannot be done.

Apple does not provider any public API for iOS or Xcode to directly access the contents of any group messages in the **Messages** app. (This is very different form accessing the **Contacts** app)

You can get user's contact using the `Contacts` framework and send messages using the `MessageUI` framework, but you will not be able to get any individual or group contact information.

> Apple's developer guidelines prioritize user privacy and place strict limitations on accessing and manipulating user data, including messages and contacts.

You can checkout some of the details here: [User Privacy and Data Use](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/user-privacy-and-data-use/)

However, in my past experience, if you think your use case is strong enough, you can try to contact the Apple developer support team to see is there any work around for you.